# Delay without sleep in vb 6

Tags: vb6, logic, delay, delayed-execution

I have a requirement in visual basic6 where I want to send commands to a machine connected to my PC. I can send the command only after getting the acknowledgement from it.It is like this. Sleep after I send the first command will make the program inactive and I cannot receive the acknowledgment.

So I am thinking of using variables or flags and increment in the subsequent modules for the delay. But I am not sure how to implement the thing. I have included the sample rather incomplete code for this. But I dont know how it can give the delay. I am thinking of timers,goto. Is there anyother way to implement the delay here.

Module where I send the command

//Sending Module

```
Sendcommand()

Send command CMD1.
If (flagcheck =2)
Send command CMD2.
```

Module where I receive the acknowledgment command

```
Receive command()

Select cmdname
public flagcheck=0
CASE ACK1.1
        flagcheck=flagcheck+1
CASE ACK1.2
        flagcheck=flagcheck+1
```

Comment: thanks @SLaks ..without timer can I do it with goto..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generally do something like

```
SendCommandOne

While flag = 0 ' ReceiveCommand would set flag to 1
    DoEvents
End While

SendCommandTwo
```

etc

Comment: +1, IMO this is the best way to implement if the delay is to wait for another process to finish.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526659/what-does-doevents-do-in-vb6 someone is not recommending using doevents..

Comment: @shivoham Good point, but this could be worked around by using static boolean variable. Which I felt obliged to add as an answer for that question.

Comment: +1 but put a tiny sleep in the loop as well as the DoEvents. Otherwise processor usage goes to 100%

Comment: DoEvents() calls actually do a long list of things, the last one being a Sleep(0) call.  It "burns rubber" because of the many operations it must perform.  Considering the re-entrancy hazard and the risk of corrupting data or blowing the stack it should be a *last resort*, not the first one.  Using a Timer is always preferable when possible.